# How can i remove an element within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, iframe

For example, I want to remove the "Navigation Bar" from the iframe. How can I do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Iframes</h2>
<p>I want to remove the navigation bar:</p>

<iframe id="" class=" " scrolling="no" style="width:1000px; height: 1500px;  overflow: hidden;" src="https://www.w3schools.com/"  title="Iframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't if iframe is from a different origin as your example is. Browsers block script access for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate what is inside an `iframe` but, if the content You want to hide is an horizontal navigation section at top of the page, you could always wrapped the `iframe` inside a `div` with `overflow:hidden` and then, move the content up with `top` propertie.

Like this:

```css
div {
  
  overflow:hidden;
}
iframe {
  position:relative; 
  top:-120px;
  border:0;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Iframes</h2>
<p>I want to remove the navigation bar:</p>
<div>
  <iframe id="" class=" " scrolling="no" style=" height: 1500px;  overflow: hidden;" src="https://www.wikipedia.org/"  title="Iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```